# Is it possible to get a rotor that is moved by kineticity of electrical current?

Tags: electric-circuits

If electrons move through a metal they hit the atoms so the atoms start vibrate and heat up. Is it possible to get kinetic energy from electrons in a form of a rotor with a copper rim conected at one end to the plus el. pole of the stator and the other on the negative el. pole where the rim is a circle cutted at one point where the ends lead to the center of the circle and are eventualy connected to the stator and the electrons moving through the rim after a while start to move the rim just exchanging its kinetic energy with the material of the rim.? [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is very little kinetic energy to tap into. The power in an electric current comes from electric and magnetic forces.

Consider a current of 1 ampere. The charge on the electron is $1.6 \times 10^{-19}$ coulomb. You might think 1 coulomb travels around the loop in 1 second, so $6 \times 10^{18}$ electrons make the trip.

The mass of an electron is $9.1 \times 10^{-31}\ \mathrm{kg}$, so the total mass is $5.7 \times 10^{-12}\ \mathrm{kg}$. Very small mass means very small energy.

This isn't really right because it isn't correct that 1 coulomb of charge moves all the way around. In reality, all the electrons in the wire move a little bit. As it turns out, they move a very little bit.

To see this, consider that protons weigh 1800 time more than electrons. Neutrons are about the same as protons, and most atoms have roughly equal numbers of each. This means that electrons are about $1/4000$th of the mass of the wire.

The wire that holds $5.7 \times 10^{-12}\ \mathrm{kg}$ of electrons therefore has a mass of $2 \times 10^{-8}\ \mathrm{kg}$. Suppose you have wire that weighs 20 grams per meter. This is enough electrons to fill about 1 micrometer of wire.

Most electrons are tightly bound to the atoms. Only the outermost electrons move. Each copper atom has 29 electrons, so this is enough outer electrons to fill 29 micrometers of wire.

So in 1 second, enough electrons are pushed onto the wire to fill 29 micrometers, all the other electrons move over 29 micrometers, and the last 29 micrometers come out the other end. All the electrons are moving at 29 micrometers per second. Again, very little kinetic energy.

Comment: So,if I understood, in other words electrons instead of  pushing the atoms forward they in reality because of small mass vibrate back and forth causing more termal effects then kinetic to the material?